# Run multiple websites/services on different subdomains with only one IP

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, domain, port, subdomain

I'm sure I can't be the first one to ask this, but I was not able to find anything that would fully apply to my scenario. So my apologies in advance, in case this has been asked before.

I have a VPS that I just set up with debian 8. It has one IP. And I bought a domain.
On that server I'm running a lot of different services. For example GitLab, and Apache.

Apache and GitLab both run on port 80.

Is there any chance I could make Apache available through `apache.mydomain.com:80` and GitLab through `gitlab.mydomain.com:80`?

I know that I can make GitLab use a different port, but I really want it to be accessable through `gitlab.mydomain.com` directly. And that's what's twisting my mind, because I can only open ports in my firewall, I can't assign them to a subdomain or so.
During my search I also found out about `Virtual hosts`, but that seems to be specific to Apache. I also found out about `SVC Records`, but people say that browsers don't really support that yet...  which would obviously defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would setup apache on port 80 and add a VirtualHost for *gitlab.mydomain.com* .

Then setup that VirtualHost with mod_proxy to http://127.0.0.1:8080 .

Finally, setup gitlab to listen on 127.0.0.1.

Found an example for you on 
GitHub: https://gist.github.com/radmen/3689615

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Could I use the same approach to allow running OpenVPN on `vpn.mydomain.com:443`. I'm asking because a service like OpenVPN is not actually providing a website or HTTP based in general.

Comment: No, afraid you can only proxy http requests to another service.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run both Apache and OpenVPN on the same port 443 then have a look at the [sslh - Applicative protocol multiplexer](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml).

There are two articles in LinuxJournal about it: one is a short editorial
 (http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/one-port-rule-them-all) and the other explains how to set up Raspberry-Pi as a secure landing point (http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/securi-pi-using-raspberry-pi-secure-landing-point). There is an explanation on how to configure SSLH on the [page 4](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/securi-pi-using-raspberry-pi-secure-landing-point?page=0,3) of the second article.

However if you don't intend supporting https on any of the VirtualHosts running on that server you can disable it in Apache configuration and configure OpenVPN to use port 443 instead.